# Calculating 2 ^ 10

Tags: javascript

```
   // CALCULATE 2 ^ 10
   var base = 2;
   var power = 0;
   var answer = 1; 

   while ( power < 10 )
   {
      answer = base * 2;
      power = power +  1;  
   }

   alert(answer);
```

Why doesn't this produce 1024? It prints 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `base * 2` will always be 4.

I believe this line:

```
answer = base * 2;
```

Should be

```
answer = answer * base;
```

Comment: +1 From me. @industrian: This is the reason why your code is not working.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't really answer your question (as to *why* the wrong value is generated) but you can use [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/Pow) to calculate the result:

```
alert(Math.pow(2, 10));
```

Comment: Yeah you could, except I'm going through exercises in a book, and we haven't gotten there yet. There exact words were 'using what you have learnt so far'... Thank you for answering anyway (and for modifying your answer).

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is flawed:

```
...
answer = base * 2; 
...
```

This resolves to `answer = 2 * 2`, no matter how many times you increment the loop. `base` does not change.

Answer (score 2):

Because `answer = base * 2;` every iteration. Since `base` never changes, every iteration you are doing `answer = 2 * 2;`.

See other answers for what you *should* be doing.

Answer (score 2):

This is because no matter how many loop cycles you do, you always multiply base (2) by 2 and assign the result to `answer` variable. So be it one or million base, the answer will always be 4.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the result of each oparation, like this:

```
    var base = 2;
    var power = 1;
    var answer = 1; 

    answer = base;

     while ( power < 10 ) { 
        answer = answer * base;
        power = power + 1;  
     }

     alert(answer);
```

This helps you?

Comment: Before the loop, I used answer = base to define base^1, then multiply it not by 2, but base again, so your script could use diferent bases.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for homework...  A dynamic programming solution which will help when you get into recursion and other fun stuff:

This solution is log(y) in terms of calculations.

```
  function powers(x,y) {
        if(y == 0) {
                return 1;
        } else if(y == 1) {
                return x;
        } else if(y == 2) {
                return x*x;
        } else if(y%2==0) {
                var a = powers(x,y/2); 
                return a * a;
        } else {
                var pow = y-1;
                var a = powers(x,pow/2);
                return x * a * a;
        }
}
```

If not use Math.pow()

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the math power method for javascript:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp

Answer (score -1):

yo should do this

```
var base = 2;
var power = 0;
var answer = 1; 
while ( power < 10 )
{
   answer = answer * 2;
   power = power +  1;  
}

alert(answer);
```

You have to increment answer otherwise It will always have the same value

Comment: `1 + 1*2` -> `3 + 1*2` -> `5 + 1*2` etc... Try `answer *= 2` instead.